# getting error in establishing a database connection (pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to use pyodbc with sql server. However I am getting the following error:

> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)').

This is my connection code

```
odbc_conn_str= 'DRIVER= {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=%s' %db_file
conn= pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
```

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Python?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you are trying to connect to an SQL server but using a Microsoft Access Driver. Only use a Microsoft Access Driver if connecting to an Access Database/File.

Try the following, this is why I use to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server:
`sql_connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=IPADDRESS\SQLSERVERINSTANCE;DATABASE=DBNAME;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=no;')`

Microsoft have a doc on setting up pyodbc for Microsoft SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have queries written in Microsoft Access Driver and want to access that.

Comment: In that case try installing the driver. It can be downloaded from microsoft at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

The following article helped me get connected to an Access database as well: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access